# Accesing remote EJB got error: connection refused

Tags: connection, websphere, remote-access, ejb-3.0

I'm trying to learn about implementing EJB into a Websphere Liberty Server.
I'm following the book "IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile Guide for Developers"

When I access the localhost, the client works fine. But when I try to lookup the remote interface through the hostname (or IP network address) I always get the same error

> "org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: other: corbaname evaluation error:attempt to establish connection failedError connecting to host=server1/172.0.0.12, port=2809: Connection refused: connect:  vmcid: OMG minor code: 0xa  completed: No"

I'm using WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.9 in Windows System

```java
String url = "corbaname::server1:2809#ejb/global/ITSORemoteEJBEAR/ITSORemoteEJB/HelloRemoteEJB!com.ibm.itso.ejbRemote.view.HelloRemoteEJBRemote";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default IIOP endpoint listens only on `localhost` , thats why you may have connection refused if you use hostname or IP address. Make sure you have the following in your `server.xml` file:

`<iiopEndpoint id="defaultIiopEndpoint" host="*" iiopPort="2809" />`

In the `host` attribute put a star, or hostname that you want use to access.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Gas.
I have changed the server.xml puttin these configuration, but then I have the follow error:

*[ERROR   ] CNTR4002E: No se ha podido iniciar el módulo EJB ITSORemoteEJB.jar en la aplicación ITSORemoteEJBEAR. El mensaje de la excepción es: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:587)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.remote.internal.EJBRemoteRuntimeImpl.bind(EJBRemoteRuntimeImpl.java:187)
    ... 1 more
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0106E: No se ha podido iniciar la aplicación web ITSORemoteEJBEAR.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0002E: Se ha producido una excepción al iniciar la aplicación ITSORemoteEJBEAR. El mensaje de la excepción es: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.NullPointerException*

Searching the web this issue my be caused due a bug in my Websphere version?

*(WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.9/wlp-1.0.12.cl50920160227-1523) en Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, versión 1.7.0_80-b15 (es_ES)*

I'm searching a 8.5.5.x version or upgrade but I'm a litle lost. There are a lot of versions and fixed packs. Do you know any link for download a 8.5.x version?

I prefer a 8.5.5.x or 8.5.x version beacuse is the same than production environement
Thanks!

Comment: Version 8.5.x of Liberty is ancient. You really need to use something more recent like 19.0.0.x. You can download Liberty from wasdev.net site. And also create `jvm.options` file with `-Duser.language=en` as these logs are unreadable ;-). Please update your original question, not create answers.

Comment: Thanks now Gas. Update to a version Higher than 8.5.x is not posible due 3th parth apps requierement. I'll try to apply a fix pack to 8.5.5.X or leave EJBs approach :(

Comment: What requirements??? The 19.0.0.x is fully backward compatible with any of previous Liberty versions. So whatever you run on Liberty 8.5, can be run on 19 thats the power of Liberty.

Comment: Moreover, if you go to the WebSphere 8.5.5.15 fixpack page, it actually points you to Liberty 19.x version -  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=ibm10871944